# How can I parse text from rich text format files like (.doc, .pages, .docx, etc.)

Tags: ios, swift, string, xcode, parsing

How can i parse text from docx file?

I already tried `Data(contentsOf:)` and `String(contentsOf:)` but nothing worked.

Comment: What is your file exactly? Rtf? A .doc might not be readable in utf8. Not all file are convertible to UTF8 string. For instance, and Image isn't.

Comment: the file that i'm trying to read is in .pages format. i also want to be able to read .doc/.docx format. i have tried using different encoding but no luck.

Comment: You cannot do it like that. It’s not a valid utf8 file. And it’s proprietary format too.

Comment: so how can i parse parse text from rtf?

Comment: For rtf, there is a NsAttributedString.DocilentType specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done using `Data(contentsOf:)` or `String(contentsOf:)` because `.docx` format is a zipped format consists of xml and other files. In order to parse the text from the `.docx` file, you should unzip the doc file. In my case, I used [ZIPFoundation](https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation) to unzip the document. Parse the file named `word/document.xml` under the extract path using any XML Parser and you will be able to get the text from the document.

**Sources:**

[Converting Docx Files To Text In Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40443609/converting-docx-files-to-text-in-swift)

[Reading or Converting word .doc files iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231068/reading-or-converting-word-doc-files-ios)